# want to display youtube play button for ios and cannot

Tags: javascript, ios7, html5-video, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am using the youtube iframe javascript api, and my videos are not playing in ios7. I've noticed that there is a play button within the iframe which is hidden by youtube's own stylesheets (or rather, set to a height and width of 1px !important). If I use safari's debugger with the ios7 simulator to remove these styles, the play button is visible, and when clicked, allows the video to play in ios.

The problem is, I cannot write a style in my stylesheets which overrides this behavior! How can I solve this issue? Attached is a screenshot of the offending style, and below is my code to initiate the player:

```
var videoOptions = {
        'controls': 0,
        'playsinline' : 1,
        'showinfo': 0,
        'html5':1,
        'modestbranding': 1,
        'autoplay': 0,
        'rel': 0,
        'enablejsapi' : 1,
        //'origin': window.location.origin,
        'wmode': 'opaque'
      };
      $scope.jsPlayer = new YT.Player('story-video-player-container', {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',

        videoId: $scope.currentVideo.youtube_id,
        events: {
              'onReady': $scope.onPlayerReady,
              'onStateChange': $scope.onPlayerStateChange,
              'onPlaybackQualityChange': $scope.onPlaybackQualityChange
        },
        playerVars: videoOptions,
      });
```

I've tried changing all of the videoOptions to show all controls / info / branding / etc, nothing works.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=5204) that Google says is "fixed" but other developers (including ourselves) insist is not. I've referenced your question there. You may want to follow this but report and add your own voice to the discussion.

At this point, this appears to be something controlled entirely on Youtube's end because it sets the size of the video tag inside the html5-video-container to 1px.

In our case, we have the iframe embedded on the page, and then a button that runs javascript to display the hidden div element so the video appears, and also trigger the YouTube API play event to make the video play (example: http://www.3708colet.com).

But Google says this is the same as "autoplay" and is disabled by iOS (it's also evidently disabled by Android Chrome--in our tests it's broken there too). Instead of playing, in iOS at least, it shows a 1px white square in the upper left corner of our container where the iframe is. And if we click that, it triggers "interaction" with the video and loads the video (doesn't work for Android). So there are no errors, but youtube's page just doesn't make that video large enough to fill the iframe area.